# Magento2: Lareyed navigation - how to select multi category name

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

Currently from filter is possible only select one option from one attribute:
https://prnt.sc/tkjrep

Is any way to display products from example both option from one attribute?

**example:**
https://prnt.sc/tkjru2

I try combinate in this way:

[https://domain.com/women/beauty-women/makeup-women.html?cat=1561`?cat=1551`](https://domain.com/women/beauty-women/makeup-women.html?cat=1561%60?cat=1551%60)

add second to url: `?cat=1551`  but this solultion no work.

Any other soltuion?